# Converting control characters to XML?

Tags: jpeg2000

The JPEG-2000 standard says that the file type box contains a series of compatibility list fields. It says this about each field:

> This field is encoded as a four-byte string of ISO/IEC 646 characters.

Here is a compatibility list field from one JPEG-2000 file (hex bytes):

```
00 00 00 B5
```

How is that four-byte encoding of a string represented in XML, given that hex 00 (nul) is not a valid character in XML?

Comment: A link to that section of the documentation for context might be useful.

Comment: Hello Andrew. My quote came from section I.5.2 of the Part 1 document. Since the documents are not online (they must be purchased from ISO) I can't provide a link.

Comment: Are you looking to represent the binary data of jpeg2000 boxes as XML entities? Is there perhaps some EXIF entity already defined for it so that you can give a chance of compatibility with other software? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) suggests to me that ISO/IEC 12234-1.4 might have relevant information.

Comment: You could just use Base64 encoding for the binary values if there is no sensible text alternative.